# how to connect Microsoft Access Database to visual c#?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

how to onnect Microsoft Access Database to visual c#

for example:
i make a database that have a table named "student" and fields " id , name " 
so i make a c# form that have 2 text boxs and a button "add" that add the contents of the two text box to the database

bye

Answer (score 3):

Here's an [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx) of the process on MSDN you might take a look at. Don't hesitate to ask if you encounter some specific problem implementing the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to have [`MDAC`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c050fe3-c795-4b7d-b037-185d0506396c&displaylang=en) (Microsoft Data Access Components).

In order to help you with the connection string and its parameters for a data file such as an Access database, please follow the following link specific to Access: [`Access`](http://connectionstrings.com/access).

For other connection strings in general: [`ConnectionStrings.com`](http://connectionstrings.com/).

In short, you need to specify your complet filename to the Access database file in your connectionString.

```
using (OleDBConnection connection = new OleDBConnection(connectiongString)) {
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        connection.Open();

    string sql = "INSERT INTO Student (Id, Name) VALUES (@idParameter, @nameParameter)"

    using (OleDBCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OleDBParameter idParameter = command.CreateParameter()
        idParameter.DbType = System.Int32;
        idParameter.Direction = Parameterdirection.Input;
        idParameter.Name = "@idParameter";
        idParameter.Value = studentId; // Where studentId is an int variable that holds your parsed TextBox.Text property value.

        OleDBParameter nameParameter = command.CreateParameter()
        // Do the same as you did above for the nameParameter.

        try {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        } finally {
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

> **Disclaimer** This code is provided as-is as it was not compiled nor tested. That is only to show you the idea of how it works. Further tests might be necessary depending on your project architecture or else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ado.net database connection objects from within the **System.Data.OleDb** namespace.  These object include the following

**OleDbConnection 
OleDbCommand
OleDbDataReader**

Additionally, here is the [quick tutorial from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx) to get you up and running.

Enjoy!